# Get HTML Source from Chromium Embedded

Tags: delphi, google-chrome, delphi-xe2, tchromium

How to do this with Delphi Chromium Embedded Component i know how to do this with TWebBrowser. But since no docs are present for this I am sure someone else had same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you do it..

```
procedure TCustomLoad.OnLoadEnd(const browser: ICefBrowser;
  const frame: ICefFrame; httpStatusCode: Integer);
  var
  data:tstringlist;
begin
  data:=tstringlist.create;
  if frame.IsMain then
  data.text:=frame.Source; // HTML Source    
end;
  data.free;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

in dcef 3

```
procedure StringVisitor(const str: ustring);
begin
  //str is the SourceHtml
showmessage(str);
end;

function GetSourceHTML: string;
var
CefStringVisitor:ICefStringVisitor;
begin
  CefStringVisitor := TCefFastStringVisitor.Create(StringVisitor);
  Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.GetSource(CefStringVisitor);
end;
```

Comment: Warning : StringVisitor procedure is called asynchronously

Comment: @STBLand In this case it seems the page is reloaded. How to get the source without reloading the page ?