# how to html getsource in delphi cef3 component?

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I want to load webpage html source into a Delphi (delphi 7) memo. It seems there are two methods for getting the source:

```
chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.GetSource(const visitor: icefstringvisitor);

chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.GetSourceproc(const proc: icefstringvisitorproc);
```

Can you please show how to use them. What is difference?

Thanks.

Update:

LD RD suggests in comments:
The GetSourceProc usage is exemplified in the examples following the source of TChromium, see GUIClient Main.pas

It works now, using GetSourceproc(const proc: icefstringvisitorproc);

Thank LD RD.

But i still do not know how to use MainFrame.GetSource(const visitor: icefstringvisitor);

Comment: [Get HTML Source from Chromium Embedded](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13324095/576719)

Comment: The `GetSourceProc` usage is exemplified in the examples following the source of `TChromium`, see [GUIClient Main.pas](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3/blob/master/demos/guiclient/main.pas).

Comment: @LU RD thanks, the first answer you mentioned the post used frame.Source property, where is this property. The second answer used two procedures. Where to put these two procedures.  I am using delphi 7. How to call the two procedures? thanks.

Comment: @LURD, thanks, I copied exactly the code you mentioned. It can compile but when I tried to get source, Access violation prompts at this line: chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.GetSourceProc(CallbackGetSource);