# How to get the text in TChromiumDevTools

Tags: delphi, chromium

For some reasons, I need to get the text inside ChromiumDevTools.Is that even possible?[image]. I just need the text in the ***elements*** tab.

```
memo1.Text := idHttp.Get(url); // doesn't get the job done 100%, that is why I need the text inside the ChromiumDevTools
```

Comment: You can access the DOM, just like the devtools are doing?

Comment: I mean in codes.. something like memo1.Text := DevTools.GetText

Comment: what the tools are showing you is the Document Object Model (aka DOM). Search for "chromium visit dom" here on SO.

Comment: This may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324095/get-html-source-from-chromium-embedded

Comment: its all I wanted thanks